# JavaScript equivalent of Python's parameterised string.format() function

Tags: javascript, python, string-formatting

Here is the Python example

```
>>> 'Coordinates: {latitude}, {longitude}'.format(latitude='37.24N', longitude='-115.81W')

'Coordinates: 37.24N, -115.81W'
```

I am looking for a way to emulate this behavior in JavaScript. As I have plenty of templates strings as `"""{} lorem {} ipsum"""` and bunch of JSON objects as k,v pairs that correspond to parameters & values.

I hate to implement my own parser if something equivalent already exist. Any similar libraries would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can consider using template strings for this purpose.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript this is called Template Literals. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It works similar to the Python format function but its done inline.

```
`string text ${some_variable} string text`
```

Where the ` back tick starts and ends the string. Inside the back ticks any ${*variable*} will be converted to the value of the variable. Just make sure the variable is in the scope of the string you are trying to format.

Comment: Except it seems to lack all the template arguments that let Python actually control the format? Right-align, left-align, control padding character, etc.