# Formatting Discord NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been coding with Python for Discord but I wanted to make the switch to JS as there is more. I'm having trouble formatting a line of code, I've downloaded this music bot to test and be come familiar with JS. It was sending an embed but I want text. Here is the line of code:

```
if (this.textChannel) this.textChannel.send(f"Playing  Now playing ${this.current.info.title} - Right Now!");
```

I know in Python it would be something like:
`await ctx.send(f"Playing  Now playing ${this.current.info.title} - Right Now!")`.

What is the equivalent to f?

Comment: Please do not use a stack snippet for code that isn't runnable. Stack snippets are only meant for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code that can be run on a browser. Please format your code using a [code block](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/8289918) instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript equivalent of Python's parameterised string.format() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520792/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-parameterised-string-format-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, use backticks (`) for a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
let a = 123;
console.log(`a is ${a}`);
```

If you need to write backticks (for markdown code block) within a template string, you can escape them with backslashes.

```js
let code = "I am some code";
console.log(`\`\`\`${code}\`\`\``);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! How would I do that as a code block so I want ${this.current.info.title} to be a code block?

Comment: You can [escape backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803959/template-literals-with-nested-backticks-in-es6) within the template string.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted if you find it useful.

Comment: Yep done! Still getting use to this i've never used it. Thanks for your help!